# Calling isset() vs. returning undefined index

Tags: php, arrays, performance, warnings

I have code that is used very extensively which fetches an array from another method, and sometimes returns the first element of that array. Given that `null` is an acceptable return value for the function, is it worth the performance overhead of calling `isset()` on the array index (or checking the array length, etc), or is it better to just return the non-existant index (warnings aside). What are the advantages of calling `isset()` aside from preventing the warning.

The example below is simplified, the real function doesn't *just* get the first element of the array.

Return index which may not exist:

```
function get_array_element(){
    $array = get_array();       // function that returns array
    return $array[0];           // return index 0 which may not exist
}
```

Versus checking if index is set:

```
function get_array_element(){
    $array = get_array();       // function that returns array
    return (isset($array[0]))?  // check if index 0 isset() else return null
        $array[0] : 
        null; 
}
```

Comment: well the first method will throw an exception (if it is null). You can of course catch it but that will in its self be more effort than checking first.

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception, just a notice. From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) `When error_reporting is set to show E_NOTICE level errors (by setting it to E_ALL, for example), such uses will become immediately visible. By default, error_reporting is set not to show notices.`

Comment: I'm of the belief that a page should never have any warnings or errors. I think that it helps enforce good programming conventions (How will a future developer who sees the warning know that the behavior is intentional rather than you forgetting an edge case?) But I also don't see a need to use `isset()` on an element of an array. Instead I would check the `count()` of `$array` to see if there is at least one element.

Comment: @StephenBooher the OCD in me agrees, but since this is called (tens of) thousands of times, I was wondering if the check was worth it performance wise, especially given that it usually contains a value.

Comment: ok then is the `E_NOTICE` less overhead than calling the `isset()` function, or swallowing the error.  Most likely the function would cost more.  I have always used `isset()` thinking that it was best practices, but it is likely less efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throwing a notice when accessing an undefined index -- in theory -- should alert you for typos in key names. In practice, if you’re using `isset` first, you probably just copied the key name there. Or used a numeric index. Or a constant.

On the other hand, in most cases you’re accessing an index withour caring wether it’s set or not -- and in this scenario, using `isset` is just anoying. A lot of languages lets you just retrieve any index without warnings, Javascript for example: just returning an `undefined`.

So I would advice to ignore the notice. Not all of them, because in some cases there really *are* helpful, so keep them turned on in development, but silence such array access by using `@`. Yes, it is ugly, but does its job:

```
return @$array[0];
```

Or in simple cases, maybe other solutions fit?

```
return array_shift($array);
```

Comment: Ahh, the `@` is what was escaping me. In this case I **know** that it's fine to return an undefined index, but it was actually making debugging other notices harder due to all the noise generated by this method. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Calling isset inside that function is semi-pointless because you are returning null if it doesn't exist, but null will be returned from $array[0] regardless of whether you use isset of not.

If it only throws an E_NOTICE then I wouldn't worry about it, just check for get_array_element() == null.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I don't think he is saying to call `isset()` on the function, just to test if the result is `null`, which I am doing. Is there any harm in just allowing the notice, or is it actually better to ignore it given that it is one less `if` in the code.

Comment: @doublesharp: In a previous edit, he had that line of code.  He since removed it making my comment moot.

Comment: Yeah i realised :/ not long woke up, my bad